# How to return a statements in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspChangeMemberRole]
    @TeamID INT,
    @MemberID INT,
    @MemberRole TINYINT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[TeamMember] 
    SET MemberRole = @MemberRole 
    WHERE TeamID = @TeamID 
      AND MemberID = @MemberID;

    RETURN @MemberRole;
END
```

When I execute this procedure I want to return "MemberRole Successfully Changed".

Please give me a solution how to return

Comment: Is this really MySQL??? Looks more like SQL Server to me...

Comment: The return value from a stored procedure can **only** be an `INT` that is usually used to indicate the number of rows affected (by a `DELETE`, `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement), or some success/error indicator. You **cannot** send back a string as a **return value** from a stored procedure in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Use [Row Count](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) to check if there are affected rows (identified if update is successful) then select a string.

> RowCount - Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT 'Member Role Successfully Chnaged';
END
```

And I think this statement is not necessary since this is an input parameter, you can get outside the proc.

```
return @MemberRole;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your return to select, and replace the datatype of your output parameter with varchar.

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspChangeMemberRole]
    @TeamID INT,
    @MemberID INT,
    @MemberRole VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
    AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[TeamMember] SET MemberRole=@MemberRole WHERE TeamID=@TeamID AND MemberID=@MemberID;

    SET @MemberRole = 'MemberRole Successfully Changed.'

    SELECT @MemberRole AS 'RETURN';
```

Comment: The return type from a SQL Server stored procedure can **ONLY** be an integer-style value - you **CANNOT** return a string from a SQL Server stored procedure with the `RETURN` command ... (you *can* pass it back as an `OUTPUT` parameter - yes - but not as via `RETURN`) ....

Comment: @marc_s , Yup i forgot to replace the `RETURN` with `SELECT` , code above already modified.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some of the concept that will help you to understand how **Procedure's** will return values.

1. If you want to return something from SQL Server to Frontend, Just use "**select**" statement.
2. You have to use proper command from frontend like you want to return scalar value, or query.